# Wordpress custom addition to mod_rewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

This is driving me nuts. I've tried everything, and nothing seems to work. I need to turn this:

```
http://www.my-domain/search-states/MI/48223/
```

into this:

```
http://www.my-domain/search-states/?state=MI&zip=48223
```

without breaking any of the other pages on the site. The site is powered by Wordpress. Modifications to .htaccess have failed, and I've not been able to make sense of WP's add_rewrite_rule().

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(search-states)/([A-Z]{2})/(\d+)/$ $1/?state=MI&zip=48223 [L,QSA]
```